# How to validate unique username in angular-js(cakephp3)?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, api, angularjs-directive, cakephp-3.0

```
<input type="email" id="username"    dbrans-validate-async="{unique: isUsernameUnique}"  ng-model="username" required  class="form-control" name="username">

 $scope.isUsernameUnique = function(username) { 
  $http.get(url+'/isUsernameUnique' + username).then(function() {
    return $q.reject(); // 200 - user exists
  }, function() {
    return true; // 404 - user does not exist
  });
};
```

what will be the api for this my database table name is users.i want to validate unique username in cakephp3 and how do i check it ontouched for empty and wrong and on form submit .plz help soon.

Comment: but i want to show the error  on touch event or onblur event....but your cake code can also help me.

Comment: can anyone help me here?

Answer (score 0):

By considering you are working for users table:-

Use this function in your UsersTable.php file(In Users model)

```
public function buildRules(RulesChecker $rules)
{
    $rules->add($rules->isUnique(['username']));
    return $rules;
}
```

> Don't forget to use namespace "use Cake\ORM\RulesChecker;"

Comment: thnx ..but i hv applied this earlier.can u tell me that hw can i shw message for this rule after button click?

Comment: You have to modify your question. You want to validate in the frontend, Cake can't help you in this regard.  Still, you can create an ajax call onBlur event, to a method/function to check the uniqueness of username. @ravneet

Comment: If you want, I can help you with the function to check uniqueness. @ravneet